# How Can I Use rest_enable_access in Restful Codeigniter?

Tags: xml, codeigniter, rest

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| REST Method Access Control
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| When set to TRUE, the REST API will check the access table to see if
| the API key can access that controller. 'rest_enable_keys' must be enabled
| to use this
|
| Default table schema:
|   CREATE TABLE `access` (
|       `id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
|       `key` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|       `controller` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|       `date_created` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
|       `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
|       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
|    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
|
*/

$config['rest_enable_access'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: creating the table access, but i don't know how to use that for my web service

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Create a table with name 'ci_api_access' in your BD:

`CREATE TABLE`ci_api_access`(
|`id`INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
|`key`VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|`controller`VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
|`date_created`DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
|`date_modified`TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
|       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
|    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

**2** Set 'rest_enable_access'] to TRUE:

```
$config['rest_enable_access'] = TRUE;
```

**3** Insert into table *ci_api_access* any values:

(sample)

```
INSERT INTO ci_api_access id, key, controller, date_created, date_modified 
VALUES ('', 'YOUR_KEY', 'YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME', '2016-04-02 00:00:00', '2016-04-02 00:00:00');
```

Watch this tutorial, to learn how to secure your  API:
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z1xGdMONnOE](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/issues/268)

### **IMPORTANT:**

REST Access Control method has a problem with the *Controller Name*, you need to fix it by following these instructions :
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/issues/268